# IPsec strongswan implementation with same subnets on both sides

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables

0

Aoa, Hello I am working on similar configuration just like mentioned in below link:

https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/net2net-same-nets/

except I have no webserver(192.168.0.150) mentioned in the link.

My configuration is written below:

**Cli1(10.10.3.12)---(10.10.3.10)UbuntuServ1(192.168.0.2)====(192.168.0.3)UbuntuServ2(10.10.3.11)---(10.10.3.13)Cli2**

But I have to add some **NETMAP and MARK iptables** and I am very much **less familiar with iptables**. How I would add iptables according to my configuration mentioned in above link.

Thanks.

Comment: Just leave out all mentions of 192.168.0.150 in the iptables files.

Comment: I have copied ipsec.conf, and ipsec.secrets according to my ip addresses. used shared pre key instead certification. And copy all iptables rules on both sides in /ufw/before.rules file , my firewall is enables on both gateways and disabled on both clients. but the clients do not ping each other

Comment: Malik what shoul I write instead of eth0 and eth1